# Specified cast is not valid when trying to insert a two letter char

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

So I have something like this in my code

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT PERSON (FIRST_NAME, SURNAME, FIRST_CODE, SECOND_CODE) VALUES (@FIRST_NAME, @SURNAME, @FIRST_CODE, @SECOND_CODE)";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", "Testo"); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SURNAME", "Tester"); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_CODE", 'A'); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECOND_CODE", "CA");
```

And in the DB the table PERSON looks like this

```
[FIRST_NAME] [varchar](20) NULL,
[SURNAME] [varchar](20) NULL,
[FIRST_CODE] [char](1) NULL,
[SECOND_CODE] [char](2) NULL,
```

The problem is, when I execute the `SqlCommand` I get an exception saying

> Specified cast is not valid.

I'm almost sure the problems is originating on the cast of the `SECOND_CODE` char asking for a `char(2)`. The `FIRST_CODE` on the other hand works fine. So am I adding the `SECOND_CODE` parameter correctly? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You can't use Single quote on `CA` in C#. single quote is for a single character.

Comment: @believeme Yeah, but then Visual Studio will say that, it is not a correct character literal.

Comment: I believe you are getting the error on `First_CODE` and not on `SECOND_CODE` as you suspect, try enclising `First_CODE` value in double quote as well.

Comment: Also, do not use `AddWithValue` if you are not sure about the data type of parameter, you can use `Add` and specify the data type explicitly.

Comment: All you arguments in AddWithValue() should use double-quotes, not the single-quote you used on one of them.

Comment: Please "script" table definition for person, and show all other fields as well. The problem may be related to fields that you do not set.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, will do.

Comment: Can't reproduce this - works just fine with VS 2015 and SQL Server 2014 ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely inserting a `char` into `FIRST_CODE`, which is `CHAR(1)`. This is a `string` type with a limitation of a single character, not a single-character type. RDBMS will report a data truncation error if you try to insert a `string` that is more than one character long, but it expects you to provide a `string`, not `char`.

This should work:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_CODE", "A");
```

Refer to the [table that maps SQL Server's type to types of .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Yeah, a co-worker told that to me but even using double quotes is giving me the same exception. The link seems pretty useful though.

Comment: @Zerjack That's very strange: the mapping table says that `char[...]` of SQL Server maps to `System.String`. Are you sure the exception comes from this portion of your code?

Comment: Yeah, however there is some more stuff around that code that might be causing the exception. I'll work it a bit so I can post it here.

Comment: So I believe I found the culprit of the issue. As part of the query I was using OUTPUT INSERTED.IDENT_NUMBER to obtain a primary key. However numeric maps to decimal, instead of int, hence the exception. The records were actually inserted. So your link helped solve my issue, but my question now doesn't make sense. How should I proceed?

Comment: @Zerjack The answer matches the original question before the edit, because using `'A'` in place of `"A"` was causing the other half of the issue. You may want to roll back that edit, so that other site visitors who find your question would not get confused.